# do I have to have main function in my python code?

Tags: python, program-entry-point

Can I write a python code with a bunch of functions but without a main function. The purpose of this script is for other scripts to import some of the functions from. I will call it setvar_general.py or something which will be imported by a series of other setvar_x scripts. While these setvar_x do more specific things, setvar_general does not do any thing other than providing building blocks. Therefore there is not need for defining a main function in setvar_general.py.

I guess it all comes down to the question "do I have to have main function"?

Comment: No, main function is optional.

Comment: Note too that if you _do_ define a main function, it will not be called implicitly like in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to have a main function in Python and writing separate files *without* a main function, to be imported into other programs, is the normal and correct way of doing Python programming.

When a Python file is loaded (either using `import` or by getting executed from the command line) each statement in the program is executed *at that time*.  Statements that are `def` or `class` statements create a function or class definition for later use.  Statements that are are not inside a `def` or `class` will be executed right away.

Therefore, the equivalent of a `main()` function in other languages is actually the set of executable statements found in your file.  If you limit these to `def` and/or `class` statements, you will get the effect you want.